# D8: Program type already present: androidx.renderscript.Allocation$1

Tags: react-native, android-build, android-buildconfig

I have a react-native application, using RN 0.62.2, that is working properly.
When trying to use hermes instead of JSC, I am getting the following error during build:

```
D8: Program type already present: androidx.renderscript.Allocation$1
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
Program type already present: androidx.renderscript.Allocation$1
Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
```

Any idea what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running `cd android && ./gradlew clean` after switching from jsc to hermes, as the docs suggest (https://reactnative.dev/docs/hermes)?